# How do i set a private ssh key for hudson / jenkins to access bitbucket?

Tags: mercurial, ssh, hudson, jenkins, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up a Debian server with Apache2 as a front end to Tomcat 7 running Jenkins - which is working - but i want Jenkins to monitor a private Mercurial repository hosted at bitbucket and I'd like to use SSH. (I've tried with plain https but still no joy - there is a question answer here on SO that recommends using ssh)

I've deployed Jenkins using the hot deploy capability of Tomcat by dropping the Jenkins .WAR file into /webapps.  I can generate a public/private key pair on the server and have added my public key to the bitbucket account - but how do I make Jenkins use my private key to authenticate when accessing a private repository on bitbucket?

I've seen a blog post that uses apt-get to install Hudson on Debian which creates a Hudson user (so i could add a private key for this user) but installing it via the tomcat autodeploy doesn't add a Jenkins user. If there is no unix user set up for Jenkins, can I configure one that Jenkins would use when authenticating?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can control the mercurial command line from within Jenkins you can pass the `--ssh` command to tell mercurial what ssh command to invoke.  Something like this would probably work:

```
hg --ssh '/usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/private/key' ...
```

Alternately you can figure out what user Jenkins is running as (it's got to be *some* user) and put the file in that user's `~/.ssh` even if that's `/root/.ssh/`

Comment: It runs as the tomcat user so I generated a ssh key pair for that and it now connects. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to do this for Windows but Hudson job just stalls. I believe is waiting for a password prompt because doing it manually I have to enter the password of the private key (TortoiseHG plinlk). Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, yeah, you'll want a passwordless private key for this one.  Alternately you can use pagent and keep that running, but passwordless key for an automated user is reasonable so long as you can't use it to get a full shell.